# How to send tradingview alerts in pinescript on candle close after checking a condition between running candle and historical candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, alerts

I have a requirement to take entry in running candle and exit immediately on candle close if my conditions are not met.
I am trying to send alerts on candle close by checking condition on running candle and historical candle.

below is my pseudo code:

```
LowerWickRange() =>
    math.min(open, close) - low

UpperWickRange() =>
    high - math.max(open, close)

if(barstate.IsConfirmed and close<high[10] and UpperWickRange>LowerWickRange())
{ 
//send exit alert
alert("do something message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
}
```

but my alerts are not getting triggered, may be due to condition being not matching at runtime due to index values of candles.

I think OHCL value will still represent running candle values in last update of running candle close.

Do I need to use bar_index? or another check of barstate.IsRealTimeBar?

Comment: Is this a strategy or indicator?

Comment: Please share your entire code, with only a pseudo code, you will get pseudo answer

Comment: @vitruvius its an indicator

Comment: @G.Lebret its not pseudo code anymore (i edited that), its just a section of real code snippet from my custom indicator, I hope its understandable now.

Comment: @nks without the entire code it is hard to test and debug